# why is nginx is sending http 500 stale cache for a request

Tags: nginx

In my nginx configuration I have set up stale caching also not to cache 500

```
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_cache_valid 400 404 500 502 503 504 0;
```

but when I look at my access logs it responding with 500 and it is STALE. How is this possible?

```
 [29/Jun/2023:05:25:24 +0000] "GET /myurl  HTTP/1.0" 500 3780 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "47.4.103.39, 63.262.86.226" 0.238 - . ucs="STALE" "Root=1-649d15c4-08d4240e3e195a9c62ad9f18" sid="-"
```